# unmarshal xml without schema

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, schema

I am using JAXB to convert xml to object. And I am creating class manually because WS vendor does not provide us schema.

XML is:-

```
<com:DayAndTimeAvailability>
    <com:DayTypes>
        <com:MondayToSunday />
    </com:DayTypes>
    <com:OpeningHours>
        <com:TwentyFourHours />
    </com:OpeningHours>
</com:DayAndTimeAvailability>
```

I am confuse in "DayTypes" element. It can have values
`<com:MondayToFriday/>,<com:Weekend/>,<com:MondayToSunday/>, <com:Monday/>,<com:Tuesday/>, <com:Wednesday/>,<com:Thursday/>, <com:Friday/>,<com:Saturday/>, <com:Sunday/>`.
I want a String variable which have value based on upper mention elements. like if i got `<com:MondayToFriday/>` in xml then i need to save value **Monday - Friday 24 Hours a Day** in a string.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Here is a full example demonstrating how you can do this:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/represent-string-values-as-element.html

Comment: Thanks Blaise Doughan. I was searching same. Can I also do as I gave answer below.

Comment: Hi Blaise Doughan, I tried it but every time i got null in unmarshalling. unmarshal method of adaptor is not call.

Comment: Did you try my example exactly as I posted it.  Did you map the namespaces?  See http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: I map namespaces in rootelement class. Should i handle namespaces in Adaptor.

Comment: You won't be able to just map the namespaces in the root class, check out the article I linked to in my previous comment to see how the `@XmlSchema` annotation can be used for your use case.

Answer (score 2):

If you have xml, then there is no need to create classes manually.
Create xsd for this xml, then using xjc command you can generate POJO's.
To map your xml to object use this,

```
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(YourMainClass.class);
            Unmarshaller u = context.createUnmarshaller();
            yourMainClassObject= (YourMainClass) u.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));
```

Answer (score 1):

I did like this

```
@XmlRootElement(name="DayTypes")
    public static class DayTypes{
        private ElementNSImpl element;
        private String value;

        @XmlAnyElement
        public ElementNSImpl getElement() {
            return element;
        }
        public void setElement(ElementNSImpl element) {
            String nodeName = element.getNodeName();
            switch (nodeName) {
            case "com:MondayToSunday":
                setValue("Monday - Sunday 24 Hours a Day");
                break;
            case "com:MondayToFriday":
                setValue("Monday - Friday 24 Hours a Day");
                break;
            default:
                setValue(nodeName);
                break;
            }
            this.element = element;
        }

        @XmlTransient
        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
```

But i do not know that it is correct way or not.